# Show if $k$ is an integer, then $\sqrt[n]{k}$ is rational if and only if it is an integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> $(i)$ Show that if the reduced fraction $a/b$ is a root of the equation $c_0x^n + c_1x^{n-1} + \cdots + c_n = 0, $ where $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c_0,\ldots,c_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $c_0 \ne 0$, then $a \mid c_n$ and $b \mid c_0$. $(ii)$ In particular, show if $k$ is an integer, then $\sqrt[n]{k}$ is rational if and only if it is an integer.

Proof $(i)$. Since $a/b$ is reduced, we have $gcd(a,b) = 1$. Let $f(x) = c_0x^n + c_1x^{n-1} + \cdots + c_n = 0$ with $c_0 \ne 0$. Then $f(a/b) =  c_0(a/b)^n + c_1(a/b)^{n-1} + \cdots + c_{n-1}(a/b) + c_n = 0$. Multiplying $f(a/b) = 0$ by $b^n$, we obtain $ (\star) \hspace{0.2cm} c_0a^n + c_1a^{n-1}b + \cdots + c_{n-1}ab^{n-1} + c_nb^n = 0$. We may rewrite the preceding equality as $b^nc_n = -c_0a^n - c_1a^{n-1}b - \cdots - c_{n-1}ab^{n-1} = a(-c_0a^{n-1} c_1a^{n-2}b - \cdots - c_{n-1}b^{n-1}) = ak_1$ for some $k_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $gcd(a,b) = 1$, it follows that $gcd(a,b^n) = 1$, so $ a \mid c_n$. Similarly, we may manipulate $(\star)$ to obtain $c_0a_n = -c_1a^{n-1}b - \cdots - c_{n-1}ab^{n-1} - c_nb^n = b(-c_1a^{n-1}-\cdots- c_{n-1}ab^{n-2} - c_nb^{n-1}) = bk_2$ for some $k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$, and since $gcd(a,b) = 1$, we have $gcd(a^n,b) = 1$. This shows that $b \mid c_0$. $\text{ } \Box$

I have provided my proof for part $(i)$, but I am stuck on part $(ii)$. How do I show that if $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $\sqrt[n]{k} \in \mathbb{Q}$ if and only if 
$\sqrt[n]{k}$ is in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: It follows directly from part (i): if $p/q$ is a root of $x^n-k=0$ (i.e., if $p/q=\sqrt[n]{k}$), then $q$ divides $c_0$; that is, $q$ divides $1$, so $q=1$, so $p/q$ is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a/b$ is a root of $x^n-k$ then $b$ is a non-zero integer dividing $1$, that is, $b$ can be only $\pm 1$. Therefore $a/b$ is an integer.

Comment: You might mention that this is a consequence of the Rational Root Theorem.

Comment: @Lubin That's the first part, mentioned above in the question without the "Rational Root" name, so it might be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the equation $x^n - k = 0$.